# I cant start the RTABMAP_ROS - freenect problem

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, ros-kinetic, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I'm using Kinect Xbox 360 and working on NVIDIA Jetson TX2.
I installed the ROS from here: http://www.jetsonhacks.com/2017/03/27/robot-operating-system-ros-nvidia-jetson-tx2/
I can use RTABMAP normal version but can't launch the rtabmap_ros. I tried to everything for launch but it still does'nt work.
My ros directory:

Here is the error: /opt/ros/kinetic

```
[freenect.launch] is neither a launch file in package [freenect_launch] nor is [freenect_launch] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281431/i-cant-start-the-rtabmap_ros---freenect-problem/) by [mustafamertunali](https://answers.ros.org/users/33498/mustafamertunali/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, thanks for helping everyone. I solved the problem with these steps:

```
roslaunch freenect_launch freenect.launch depth_registration:=yes
roslaunch rtabmap_ros rtabmap.launch rtabmap_args:="--delete_db_on_start"
```

I think this problem is because of double freenect version. I got freenect that I installed manualy, another freenect version came from ROS. Therefore, rtabmap cant launch.

---

Originally posted by [mustafamertunali](https://answers.ros.org/users/33498/mustafamertunali/) with karma: 16 on 2018-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0